# Format tables in reStructuredText

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have a table issue when using `Sphinx` with the [bootstrap](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sphinx-bootstrap-theme/) theme (`build html`).

1. Is there a way to format the table such that it wouldn't stretch on the entire screen width? I would like the columns to have the text width and the overall table to be center aligned.
2. What about column alignment? Could I center align some of the columns?

Here is a screenshot with how the table looks like right now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqwkK.jpg

Comment: Can be fixed by changing the css file of the theme.