# Setting Column Width with restructuredText Grid Tables

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have the following grid table in rST. I'd like to control the column widths **for HTML output** so that `Field type` occupies 20% of the table's width, `Description` occupies 30%, and `Example` occupies 50%.

```
+-------------+-----------------+-----------------------+
|Field type   |Description      |Example                |
+-------------+-----------------+-----------------------+
```

The `..tablularcolumns` directive has no impact, neither does the combination `..table` and `:width:`. For example, the following has no impact.

```
.. tabularcolumns:: |p{2cm}|p{3cm}|p{5cm}|
```

The answer at the following SO link does not work.

[How to fix column width in reStructuredText tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27546728/how-to-fix-column-width-in-restructuredtext-tables)

Any recommendation will be thoroughly blessed.

Comment: ``..tabularcolumns`` is only for PDF (via LaTeX) output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two options.

Use the [`widths` option](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#table) for tables.

```
.. table:: This is my table
    :widths: 20 30 50

    +-------------+-----------------+-----------------------+
    |Field type   |Description      |Example                |
    +-------------+-----------------+-----------------------+
```

Modify your theme's CSS and use the [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) CSS pseudo-selector.

```
td:nth-child(1) {
    width: 20%;
}
td:nth-child(2) {
    width: 30%;
}
td:nth-child(3) {
    width: 50%;
}
```

The output from the first option is the following:

```
<table border="1" class="colwidths-given docutils" id="id1">
<caption><span class="caption-text">This is my table</span><a class="headerlink" href="#id1" title="Permalink to this table">¶</a></caption>
<colgroup>
<col width="20%">
<col width="30%">
<col width="50%">
</colgroup>
<tbody valign="top">
<tr class="row-odd"><td>Field type</td>
<td>Description</td>
<td>Example</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Didn't work. I get the following error:

   **ERROR: Error in "table" directive: unknown option: "widths".**

Modifying the CSS is viable, but would prefer to avoid for workflow reasons.

Comment: It works for me. Perhaps you have wonky whitespace? I've edited my answer to provide the output. I'm using Sphinx 1.5.6 for this example, but most versions should support this option.

Comment: Yup, your solution works perfectly. On my Sphinx version 1.5.2 it didn't work; upgrading to 1.5.6 did work! Thank you.

Comment: Sphinx version matters. On 1.4.6 I get the "unknown option" error too.